# User permissions inheritance problem

Tags: 2013, permissions

I have the following problem with Sharepoint 2013 on-premises:
Given a site http://site/quality, and its subsite http://site/quality/dc. 
All user are organized in groups, let's take one group called MEMBERS.

MEMBERS have READ permissions on /quality.
/quality/dc inherits permissions from /quality.

The problem: User have access to /quality/dc, but not to /quality.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Error message says: "Sorry something went wrong, File not found"